# Angular - Subscribe to route.queryParams

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-observable

I've got this in my ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.sub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: any) => {
        this.data = {...params};
        this.stationsService.getStations(this.data).subscribe((res: any) => {
            this.stations = res.data.stations
        })
    });
}
```

and also have this delete function

```
deleteMass() {
    let array: any = manipulateSelections(this.selected, this.stations);
    this.stationsService.deleteStations(array).subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.data.random = Math.random();
        this.router.navigate([], {queryParams: this.data });
    })
}
```

What I'm doing. Every time I delete stations I create a random number to change me route to make the first observable runs again. Can you suggest a better way. This seems very bad practice.

Comment: You're looking for `switchMap`. Try something like `queryParams.switchmap(params => this.stationsService.getStations(params)`.

Comment: why are you generating random numbers? what is the expectation?

Comment: by using navigate I change the url, so the first observables fires again

Comment: any working example?

Comment: May we know the reason why are you redirecting to random numbers. What will happen if you don't?

Comment: Everytime I delete an item I want the deleted objects to hide. Instead of hide every item, i want to refresh my list. So if i want to trigger the this.route.queryParams.subscribe i have to change my url. Anything. And the easiest way is to put a random number to the url.